# How does the IModelBinder maintain the current state of the Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with MVC3 and using a custom ModelBinder to pass around the `ProducerListViewModel` that I built.

Here is the controller code I am currently working with:

```
    Function Filter(user As UserModel, viewModel As ProducerListViewModel) As ActionResult

        If IsNothing(viewModel) Then
            viewModel = New ProducerListViewModel(user)
        End If

        Return View(viewModel)

    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function Filter(user As UserModel, viewModel As ProducerListViewModel, <Bind(Prefix:="Filter")> filterModel As ProducerFilterModel) As ActionResult
        'update the filter in the view model and send off to the list method
        viewModel.Filter = filterModel
        Return RedirectToAction("List")
    End Function

    Function List(user As UserModel, viewModel As ProducerListViewModel) As ActionResult

        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

This is the code for the model that is bound in the custom ModelBinder

```
<Serializable()> _
<ModelBinder(GetType(ProducerListViewBinder))> _
Public Class ProducerListViewModel

    <XmlIgnore()> _
    Public Property Producers As IEnumerable(Of ProducerModel)
    Public Property PagingInfo As New PagingInfoModel("Load More Producers")
    Public Property Filter As New ProducerFilterModel()

    Public Sub New(user As UserModel)
        Me.Filter = ProducerFilterBL.Retrieve(user)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the code for the Binder:

```
Public Class ProducerListViewBinder
    Implements IModelBinder

    Private Const __sessionKey As String = "ProducerListView"

    Public Function BindModel(controllerContext As ControllerContext, bindingContext As ModelBindingContext) As Object Implements IModelBinder.BindModel

        Dim filter As ProducerListViewModel

        'check to see if the filter exists in session
        If IsNothing(controllerContext.HttpContext.Session(ProducerListViewBinder.__sessionKey)) Then
            'load existing filter for user and store for later retrieval
            Dim user As UserModel = UserBL.RetrieveUser()
            filter = New ProducerListViewModel(user)
            ProducerListViewBinder.SetItem(filter)
        Else
            filter = CType(controllerContext.HttpContext.Session(ProducerListViewBinder.__sessionKey), ProducerListViewModel)
        End If

        Return filter

    End Function

End Class
```

The flow goes like this:

1. User navigates to filter page, hitting the first action (Filter)
2. User makes changes to the filter and submits the page, hitting the second action (Filter w/ Post)
3. The filter w/ Post action receives the updated filter using model binding (third parameter `filterModel As ProducerFilterModel`), updates the `ProducerListFilterModel`, and redirects to the List action

Everything works just fine, but here is my question:

Why does the List action have the updated version of the `ProducerFilterModel` inside of the `ProducerListViewModel`?

I love that it works so perfectly, I just want to know why it works.

Comment: IModelBinder is an interface. A simple contract. It does strictly nothing. You haven't shown us the code of your `ProducerListViewBinder` custom model binder and you ask us how it works. I wonder what kind of answer do you expect to such question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I added the code for the Binder. The reason I did not think to add the code originally is because when I set a breakpoint in the 'BindModel' function it did not stop there between the second Filter action and the List action. BTW, no need to be so harsh. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have shown the code for your model binder everything is very clear. This model binder stores the `ProducerListViewModel` instance into the session which is what allows it to survive the redirect.

The first time the POST `Filter` action is hit, there's nothing in the session, so your custom model binder does some database lookup or something to retrieve the value:

```
Dim user As UserModel = UserBL.RetrieveUser()
filter = New ProducerListViewModel(user)
ProducerListViewBinder.SetItem(filter)
```

and then stores this value into the session. I guess it is the `ProducerListViewBinder.SetItem` that does this job. Unfortunately you haven't shown the code of it but I am ready to bet 5 bucks that it's what it do.

Then the `Filter` action executes, and at the end it redirects to the `List` action which takes a `ProducerListViewModel` as argument. So your custom model binder kicks in again but this time it finds the instance it previously stored into the session and it simply returns it from there.

So there's no magic here. It simply uses the ASP.NET session in order to persist the values between the redirects.